# fail to get all parameters passed to function in log4net logger

Tags: c#-4.0, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am creating a log file by using log4net, i logged the result in the .xml file, every thing is working perfect but i have one issue, i used library class and reference it in the form, in form on button click i called log function in logger file and pass four parameters i get all other records but fail to get the logging properties. i am using the fallowing code to write in the xml file.

```
public class MyXmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase
{
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    { writer.WriteStartElement("LogEntry");

        writer.WriteStartElement("Level");
        writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        }
```

and these are the parameters i am passing to the function.

```
 try
        {
            int i = 25;
            int j = 0;
            int foo = i / j;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("ErrorLog", LoggingLevel.Error, "Attempted to divide by zero.",
            new { User = "Fred Bloggs", Environment = "Production" }, ex);
        }
```

can any one tell that how i can access "User" and "Environment"???
or any other suggestion.

Comment: i was not getting any solution for this, i used xml serialization and passed object to variable to write. Now its working for me.